# Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman, first order condition and derivative of value function

Tags: reference-request, dynamic-programming, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Let $i \in I = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ denote the number of controls.
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ denote the state and let $u := (u_1, \ldots, u_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n $ denote the control vector.
The state equation reads
\begin{align}
\dot x(t) = f(x(t), u(t)).
\end{align}
The value function is given by 
\begin{align}
V(x_\tau) := \max_{u}\int^\infty_\tau{\sum_{i \in I}e^{-rt} F_i(x(t), u(t))dt}
\end{align}
where $F_i$ is some objective function and $r>0$.
The Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation reads 
\begin{align}
rV(x) = \max_u\left\{\sum_{i \in I}{F_i(x, u)} + V'(x) f(x, u)\right\}.
\label{eq:hjb_co}
\end{align}
The first order conditions read
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \in I}{\frac{\partial F_i(x, u)}{\partial u_j}} + V'(x)\frac{\partial f(x, u)}{\partial u_j} = 0 \quad \text{for } j = 1, \ldots, n
\label{eq:foc_co}
\end{align}
I'd like to solve the foc for $V'(\cdot)$.
Therefore, is the following statement true?
\begin{align}
V'(x) = -\sum_{i \in I}{\frac{\partial F_i(x, u)}{\partial u_1}}\left[\frac{\partial f(x, u)}{\partial u_1}\right]^{-1} = \ldots = -\sum_{i \in I}{\frac{\partial F_i(x, u)}{\partial u_n}}\left[\frac{\partial f(x, u)}{\partial u_n}\right]^{-1} 
\end{align}

- Could you point me to some literature?
- I'm probably not allowed to cancel out the $\partial u_j$ which does the trick, right?

Comment: The envelope theorem will be useful. See here for an example: https://personal.utdallas.edu/~sethi/Prosper/Control-Tex-Ch2.pdf